# How to fill array from list of other elements in foreach?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

i want to fill array of my types from list of other element. All of this I want to do in a foreach loop.

Is it possible?

How it is done now:

```
// Temp list
List<Parameter> inputData = new List<Parameter>();

// going through collection from which i want to copy
foreach (var parameter in parametersWindow.Parameters)
{
    inputData.Add(new Parameter() { Name = parameter.Name, Value = parameter.Value });
}

// Convertation to array.
Parameter[] parametersToInput = inputData.ToArray();
```

And this is how I want to do it:

```
Parameter[] parametersToInput = new Parameter[parametersWindow.Parameters.Count]

foreach (var param in parametersWindow.Parameters)
{
   // parametersToInput.add(new Parameter(parameter))
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You can copy an array to a new one without a loop by using the [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy.aspx) static method.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5):

An array has no `Add` method since it cannot be resized. So either also use a `List`, use `LINQ`'s `ToArray` from your list or correctly size the array and use a `for`-loop.

The linq approach is:

```
Parameter[] parametersToInput = parametersWindow.Parameters.ToArray();
```

The list:

```
List<Parameter> parametersToInput = parametersWindow.Parameters.ToList();
```

or

```
List<Parameter> parametersToInpu = new List<Parameter>(parametersWindow.Parameters);
```

The array-for-loop approach:

```
Parameter[] parametersToInput = new Parameter[parametersWindow.Parameters.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < parametersWindow.Parameters.Count; i++)
    parametersToInput[i] = parametersWindow.Parameters[i];
```

**Update** Since `parametersWindow.Parameters` is not a `Parameter` you ned to create one:

```
Parameter[] parametersToInput = parametersWindow.Parameters
    .Select(p => new Parameter {  Name = p.Name, Value = p.Value})
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Unfortunately parametersWindow.Parameters's data is not "Parameter". So it is needs some kind of "convertation"...

Comment: Arrays aren't immutable. Maybe you wanted to say "fixed-size".

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM: that was anunfortunate choice of words. Corrected it, thanks.

Comment: Ok.. as far as i understand - its no way to use foreach in this case.. Because of i need array, not list...

Answer (score 1):

If you *really wan't to do a Foreach loop*, you could try this:

```
//Your List
List<Parameter> inputData = new List<Parameter>();

//Fill Your List Here    

//Your Array
Parameter[] parametersToInput = new Parameter[inputData.Count];

//Filling Your Array from Your List
int index = 0;
inputData.ForEach(e => parametersToInput[index++] = e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? You can do this is full LINQ with no messing around with loops.

```
Parameter[] parametersToInput = parametersWindow.Select(p => p.Parameters).ToArray();
```

On line. No drama.

If you want to perform additional processing;

```
Parameter[] parametersToInput = parametersWindow.Select(p => 
{
    ProcessParameters(p);
    return p.Parameters;
}).ToArray();
```

The `Select` method is ideal for 1-to-1 type transformations. With LINQ, I don't know why you would do it any other way :)

Comment: I understand that the question requirements where 'a foreach loop' but a **foreach** is not necessarily the most appropriate tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq:

```
Parameter[] parametersToInput = parametersWindow.Parameters
                                     .Select(p => 
                                        new Parameter() { 
                                           Name = p.Name, Value = p.Value })
                                     .ToArray();
```